# Unable to achieve the mansory layout+infinite scroll on tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I've been frustrated for weeks, not been able to figure out what is wrong with my template. I used many methods in order to create the mansory layout (2 column post) but I have failed on most of them. It's my first try with java-script for the  and I'm beginning to believe either is my html / css is failing or just simply I'm not good enough for js challenge...
This is my tumblr http://thegreysanctuary.com/

```
<script>
(function () {
var $tumblelog = $('#container');
$tumblelog.infinitescroll({
    navSelector: ".pagination",
    nextSelector: ".pagination a:jump_page",
    itemSelector: ".item",
},

function (newElements) {
    var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
        opacity: 0
    });
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $newElems.animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
        $tumblelog.masonry('appended', $newElems);
    });
});
$tumblelog.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $tumblelog.masonry({
        columnWidth: function (containerWidth) {
            return containerWidth / 100;
        }
    });
 });
})();

</script>

HTML5 ------------------------------
img {
height: auto;
width: auto;
}

#container {
width: 960px;
margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
clear:both;



}

.mansory {
width:auto;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #fff;
border-style: solid;
}

.item{


width: 400px;
margin: 10px 20px 0px 10px;
border-width: 8px;
border-color: #fff;
border-style: solid;
background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
 float: left;
color: #73654D;
display: inline-block;
}

.pagination {
margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
clear: both;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hey. I find masonry to be a bit of a pain, but I have just looked on your site, and you require jquery for this to work, but I am seeing $ is not defined in the console. Add a link to jquery in the head of your document and see if that gives you any success.  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @lharby is correct, you need to include `jQuery`. Also your missing markup for your pagination, which `infinitescroller` requires.

Comment: Hi guys! sorry for the late reply, I finally got it to work...sort of. I began fixing some attributes, put the following jquery packages and tweaking together the container with the mansory IDs. I think is working. Thanks guys!